# syncadapter google spreadsheet - Android

Tags: android

What is the easiest way to use a custom sync adapter with the google spreadsheet for an android device. Can it be done by using the using the SampleSyncAdapter from google as a base. Im developing an app where the user can upload data google spreadsheet. So can it be done?

Comment: interesting idea.  You could use spreadsheets as an backend for your app as a quick and easy way to enter data...did you ever implement this?

Answer (score 0):

so you are trying to upload the data from android to spreadsheet or a spreadsheet done on android to gmail acc?..
In any case if you are trying to upload data from android to spreadsheet - I am unsure as i myself am trying to do this
But if spreadsheet done on the android and syncing it to the spreadsheet then this can be achieved.. (u can make your own syncadapter by retaining all the required classes in the api).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a *easy* way, but I don't think there is an easy way.  You could write a content provider that uses the spreadsheet api to execute CRUD operations to a spreadsheet.  The sync adapter would then use the content provider to sync automatically.